# Trying to compile application from within PHP

Tags: php, compilation, mingw32, execvp

As stated in the title, I'm trying to compile a program from within `PHP` using the `i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix` cross-compiler.

When I execute the command on the command line, it works great. However when I use the `exec` function in `PHP`, it returns me the error:

> i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No
>   such file or directory

So, I execute in PHP a command like:

```
exec('i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix ....');
```

Comment: use full path of `execvp`. Also hope you know php has limited `max_execution_time`, if the compilation takes more time, php script will stop in between. And if you are using PHP CLI, then you are fine.

Comment: @Jigar, yes. The compilation is done within my current 30 sec `max_execution_time` limit. Could you tell me how to specify the fullpath of execvp as in where and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec('/full/path/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix ....');`.

You can use tools like `whereis` or `locate` to actually get the full path.

Comment: Oh wauw, I completely missed the message pointed out as `execvp`. I thought in a complete other direction. This fixed the issue